# Properties of $L^p$ spaces norms

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the following equality correct

> $$\lVert u^q \rVert_{L^p}=\lVert u \rVert^q_{L^p}$$

or there is a relation between these two norms?

Comment: What is true, is that $\|u^q\|_{L^p}=\|u\|_{L^{pq}}^q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain of $u$, $D$, has finite measure, $|D|\lt\infty$, then for $q\ge1$ and $\frac1q+\frac1r=1$, Hölder says
$$
\begin{align}
\|u^q\|_{L^p}|D|^{\frac{q-1}{p}}
&=\left(\int_D|u|^{pq}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac1p}\left(\int_D1^r\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac{q}{pr}}\\
&\ge\left(\int_D|u|^{p}1\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large\frac{q}{p}}\\[9pt]
&=\|u\|_{L^p}^q
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't true in general.  If $S$ is our $L^p$-space, then

$$\| u^q \|_{L^p} = \left(\int_S |u(x)|^{pq} \, dx \right)^{1/p}$$

but

$$\| u \|_{L^p}^q = \left(\int_S |u(x)|^p \, dx \right)^{q/p}.$$

These two expressions on the RHS are not equal in general.  For example, take $p = 2$, $u(x) = x$, and $S = [0,1]$.

Comment: Than you, and is there any inequality between them?

Comment: @DiegoVargas, I dunno, but thinking about it briefly makes me think there isn't one in general.  I'm pretty sure it would depend on $p$, $S$, and $u(x)$.